# Collapsing toolbar does not fully display with a scroll

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

thank you in advance for your attention, I'm having some problems with the collapsing toolbar, it just does not roll fully, so it can appear the toolbar collapsing completely again.
After it stops at the "first item in recyclerView", I need to pull it down again, so it can come back, I wish with just "one roll" it would be possible to expand it again, when the first item in RecyclerView is visible.

See my problem here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7CHEy8DwYI

***my xml on > https://ghostbin.com/paste/ztpb9***

Sorry for link in ghostbin, i can't edit here.

Comment: in app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed", remove the exituntilcollapsed and type enteralways. this might help you.

Comment: I tried this, but the collapsing toolbar appears before the recyclerView displays the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that I left the collapsing toolbar aside, I was able to meet my needs with a nestedScrollView, recyclerView and a relativeLayout, thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

You can use Observable Scrollview:

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

I think,You should use parallax Scrollview and Toolbar.